# How to display all available Struts2 actions?

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, struts2-config-browser

I'm quite frequently asked to solve struts.xml configuration errors. Now, after updating to a later version of Struts2 I myself run into such a mismatch. Resulting in the following error:

```
No result defined for action com.opensource.project.ResourceAction and result missing
```

Well, solvable I guess. However, is there a smart way to html-print all available URL paths?

thanks for this community-guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with the [config-browser plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/config-browser). Check the reference docs. One of the features of that plugin is

> Shows all accessible action URLs