# Struts action not triggering

Tags: struts2

I was working/using in the application for long time and today when i tried to fix  some issues struts 2 action is not responding. I have faced the same issue in some  other application, long time back and did some setup in Eclipse / Tomcat which allocation struts 2 action to get triggered. I could see the queries running in the backend after login, for the first landing page.

Tolls / Technology stack that i am using,

1. Struts 2.0, Display Tag,  Eclipse, Tomcat

Any guess what could be that configuration? It may be filter / proxy / Something else. I couldnt recall that.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/17673308/573032

Comment: It i sworking, My Firewal is blocking.